# How to indicate location of file when sending email using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email

seems to almost work but the strlocation is showing me that there is no "\" between name of file and it's location. How do I add that.

```
Sub Macro1()
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                Filename:=Range("f6").Text, _
                                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=False


  Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
      .Subject = Range("f6").Text
      .To = "EMAIL"
      .Body = "Daily movement file attached" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _ 
              "Regards," & Chr(13) & "SCD" & Chr(13) & "AAAAAA"
      strlocation = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\macro save" & Range("f6").Text & ".pdf"
        .Attachments.Add (strlocation)
      .Send
  End With
  Set Mail_Object = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're only missing a `/`?

---

***Change this:***

```
  strlocation = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\macro save" & Range("f6").Text & ".pdf"
```

***...to this:***

```
  strlocation = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\macro save\" & Range("f6").Text & ".pdf"
```

Comment: thanks, literally tried that the first time and it gave me the error, now it works. first day of using vba and the amount of times I've been confused is insane